# Where should I cast new bullets?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Should I

- Cast new bullets from my Weapon class, which would test a flag when its updated that tells if mouse left is down, which is set by Input class
- Cast new bullets from my Input class, which would call Weapon Cast()

And why?

Comment: This really depends on what the specifics of those classes are, their other responsibilities, and how they are used in your code; as such it's a bit too much of a design discussion for the site; you might try asking in [chat].

Answer (score 1):

Your input class should tell your weapon to cast a bullet.

You'll be able to use the same functions when the bullet will need to be fired from an AI entity.

This will help separate concepts: your input class knows that the weapon can fire a bullet, but does not have to know how it's being done.